# Getting a system's date and timestamp

Tags: objective-c, datetime, xcode4.5

I have created a method to write a string of data to an text file. I was wondering how I could get the systems date and time and send it to the text file? Here is the method:

```
 -(void) writeToTextFile{

//get the documents dir
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/movbandlog.txt",
                      documentsDirectory];
//create content 
NSString *content = @"Data received from device\n \n \n \n \nData sent to Portal\n \n \n \n \nData received to Portal";

//save to documents directory
[content writeToFile:fileName
          atomically:NO
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
               error:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Pure Cocoa**

Use [`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and optionally [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) to format it:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
// NSLog(@"%@",dateString);

// Adding your dateString to your content string
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data received from device\n \n \n \n \nData sent to Portal\n \n \n \n \nData received to Portal\n \n \n \n \nData received at %@", dateString];
```

**Using Unix Functions**

You might also consider [using unix functions for unlocalized](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW12) dates (timestamps)

```
struct tm  sometime;
const char *formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z";
(void) strptime_l("2005-07-01 12:00:00 -0700", formatString, &sometime, NULL);
NSLog(@"NSDate is %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: mktime(&sometime)]);
// Output: NSDate is 2005-07-01 12:00:00 -0700
```

Comment: Of course, the usual caveats -- set timezone if it's important, set locale if you don't want to get bit by the locale feature, etc.

Comment: How would I go about adding this to my NSString *content? I need date and time listed at the top of my text file.

Comment: In your Unix Functions , I have 2 questions : 1.the `strptime_l` method will throw a warning , although I `#include <time.h>`, and how to fix it ?  2.The output date is like which you code in the `strptime_l` method ? how to output now time? thx